# Serialization,Kryo,Java compressed serialization

Tags: java, serialization

In our application we support Java,Kryo and Java compressed(deflator Stream) serialization, Is there an way that we come to know that server has done this level of serialization while sending message across , Can the client automatically deserialize the message accordingly without declaring which level of serialization is done by the server whether it is Java,Kryo,Java COmpressed).

Answer (score 0):

You can if each has a different header.  Java serialization and LZW both have special bytes at the start to say what sort of stream they are.  I imagine that kyro could, or you can add them if not.

In short, look at the first two bytes in each case for a trivial example.